# MySQL Update command

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1264

I have a query in MySQL

```
UPDATE `mylandho_foreclosure`.`property_commercial` 
SET `winningBid` = '14000000.00' 
WHERE `property_commercial`.`propertyId` =325 LIMIT 1 ;
```

but it shows warning

```
Warning: #1264 Out of range value adjusted for column 'winningBid' at row 1
```

datatype is float(9,2)

Answer (score 5):

**Float(9,2)** would allow for *7 numbers before the decimal, and 2 after*, **you have 8 before and 2 after**.

You need to increase the size of the filed if you wish to change the value to what you require.

You should have a look at [Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

> For example, a column defined as
>   FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999

Comment: Welcome to SO Rajanikant, don't forget to check this answer as the accepted one.